# Unable to call some methods from an Objective-C class in a Swift extension of that class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an objective-c class something like:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject { }

- (MyObject *)coolMethod;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (MyObject *)coolMethod {
    return [self doCoolStuff];
}

@end
```

...and a Swift extension something like:

```
extension MyClass {
    @objc func addedMethodInSwift() {
         let coolObj = coolMethod()   // <<<< compiler error - method not found
    }
}
```

The code will not compile, because the compiler cannot find the implementation of `coolMethod()`, however certain other methods from the Objective-C class can be called from the Swift extension.

I have checked and the Objective-C header file is included in the project's bridging header, so it should be visible to Swift. The method in question is definitely visible in the header file.

Why can't `coolMethod()` be called from the Swift extension?

Answer (score 1):

Check that both your objective-C class *and* the return type of the function (in your case `MyObject.h`) are included in the Bridging header. Methods with return types not included in the bridging header are not available from Swift.